# 2nd drive fills up storage space on root file system

Tags: mount, filesystem, disk-usage

Running Ubuntu 18.04 of a 256GB SSD with full disk encryption and an additional 1TB harddisk mounted for larger files. I keep getting "Low on space" notifications because "The filesystem root `/`" is filling up (supposedly).

The weird thing is, when I look at Disk Analyzer, it will also count the files stored on the 1TB drive for the used space calculation of `/`. Most space is used by the `/media/<username>/Harddisk` folder, which is the mount point for the 1TB drive:

[image: disk analyzer 1]

Any idea what's wrong here? Why does my 1TB drive mounted under `/media/<username>/Harddisk` use up space on `/`? I double checked with the command `df -h` and get the same results.

I unmounted the 1TB drive to see what happens then. The used up space disappears, but root is still almost full:

[image: Disks screenshot]

This is the SSD with full drive encryption. Its'definitely a 256GB drive:
[image]

And here's the `df -h` output:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.6G  2.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root      232G  215G  5.2G  98% /
tmpfs                            7.8G  875M  7.0G  11% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2                   705M  164M  490M  26% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                   511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
//10.127.0.199/home               11T  152G   10T   2% /media/potaito/freenas_home
//10.127.0.199/users/potaito      11T   68G   10T   1% /media/potaito/freenas_potaito
//10.127.0.199/users              11T   68G   10T   1% /media/potaito/freenas_users
```

Comment: /media is under / , so it's space will be counted as part of / .  In the beginning you mention problems with /root which is not the same as /  (/root is the root user's directory).   As an example, my current system has a 120gb drive, but if I look at my / directory it'll show 22tb of space on / as I have many NFS (network file system) directories mounted - where I store all my files.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, you are right. I'm always thinking of `/`, not `/root`.

I also have network shares with 11TB space mounted, but these are not included in the count for some reason. I edited my post and appended the `df -h` output. There it shows that 98% of `/` are in use, even though with Disk Analyzer I can only find around 100 GB actually used on the SSD.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds as if you have written data to one or more of the folders which are the mount-points of your HDD and network drives while nothing was mounted to a mount-point.

You can unmount the drives and then check the contents of this folders to see the contents of this folders while nothing is mounted.

Alternativly (while all drives are mounted) you can use a `bind mount` to see what is in this folders (mount-points) as if nothing would be mounted to them, to do that, make sure that all drives are mounted properly. Then run

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt
```

and browse to `/mnt/media/potaito/...`, this folders should be empty. If one or more of this folders are not empty, you can now either delete the files or move them to your HDD or network drive.

**Example:**

You found files in `/mnt/media/potaito/freenas_home`. To remove them all use

```
rm -R /mnt/media/potaito/freenas_home/*
```

To move them all to the network drive use

```
mv /mnt/media/potaito/freenas_home/* /media/potaito/freenas_home/
```

You can also use the file manager to delete/move the files, you'll have to decide yourself which of them to keep.

If you are done, remove the `bind mount` with

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: This is a good solution for this issue.